# How to use fs in the browser / in a HTML file?

Tags: html, node.js

I am new to node.js and I am trying to deploy a simple app that helps me merge 2 pdf files.

I have node.js installed and working. I am only testing the small app.js that contains the following:

```
console.log("Hello World");

const fs = require('fs');
```

when I run this in the console with

```
node app.js
```

The file runs and the second line doesn't generate any error. However when I include the app.js as a script in a HTML file the second line of code throws the following error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at app.js:3

What am I missing? Do I have to install node.js inside my web app folder? Do I have to include app.js in the package.json file?

Comment: This cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done. You would need something like webpack to make modular code like this run in a browser, but either way, node specific modules – like `fs`, `cluster`, `child_process`, etc – will not be able to run in the browser.